# SQLAlchemy query on Base Class including Derived Classes

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using single table inheritance configuration in sqlalchemy to create several derived classes. When querying the base class the results include all derived classes as well. I'd like the results to only include the base class.

Used example code in the sqlalchemy documentation.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text, func, and_, Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, Boolean, MetaData, Table
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, with_polymorphic, backref, relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base, declared_attr, has_inherited_table


POSTGRES = {
    'user': 'sqlalchemy',
    'pw': 'sqlalchemy',
    'db': 'sqlalchemy',
    'host': '127.0.0.1',
    'port': '5432',
}

Base = declarative_base()
meta = MetaData()

engine = create_engine('postgresql://%(user)s:%(pw)s@%(host)s:%(port)s/%(db)s' % POSTGRES, echo=False)
DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
s = DBSession()
d = {}


''' Create Base Classes using single table polymorphic identity column '''


class Person(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'people'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    discriminator = Column('type', String(50))

    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on': discriminator, 'polymorphic_identity': 'person'}


class Engineer(Person):

    primary_language = Column(String(50))

    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'engineer'}


''' Create Empty Schema '''

Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

''' Create a bunch of objects '''

for id in range(1, 11):

    s.add(Person(name='person_%s' % str(id)))
    s.add(Engineer(name='engineer_%s' % str(id)))
    s.commit()
    s.flush()

print('people: %s' % s.query(Person).count())
print('engineers: %s' % s.query(Engineer).count())

''' Person query should only have 10 results but has 20. Engineer query has 10 results. '''

s.flush()
s.close()

exit()
```

Person query should have 10 results but include Engineers also.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the only solution is to add a filter to the query.

`people = s.query(Person).filter_by(discriminator='person').all()`